# How do I install Red Hat Linux 9.0 Shrike from a USB drive?

Tags: rhel, system-installation, usb-drive

I have a desktop PC which does not have a CD drive and does not have access to the Internet or other networks.

I want to install Red Hat Linux 9.0 "Shrike" on it using a 8GB USB flash drive.

I have made a bootable USB drive using [LinuxLive USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/).

When I try to install from it, I see that the installation starts and I see the Red Hat Logo and all that and after that it is asking for the device from which to make the install.

Obviously I don't see a USB option in there. I tried to choose HDD and tried to find my UDB drive, but to no avail. I have other options like network install (FTP and HTTP) which I cannot use.

So how can I achieve this?

I am not installing it in a VM; I am trying to install it on a physical machine.

Edit: I just want to install RHL9.0 for a number of reasons, which I cannot explain here. I would be glad if I could just get a solution for this (And I do use Fedora too and I also know about CentOS. But now I want to install shrike

Comment: You probably won't be able to do this with an ancient version of Red Hat. What do you want to do with a distro that is 10 years old?

Comment: Can you care to explain why you want to install a antique  ? You propably wont have this problem with latest versions like f18 . See http://fedoraproject.org/ .